# Does Open Broadcaster Software install in CentOS6?

Tags: centos

How can I install [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/index) on CentOS 6.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By checking the [download page](https://obsproject.com/download#linux) it seems that OBS does not have an official CentOS build. It seems as though you'll have to [build it from source](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#red-hatfedora-based-build-directions) if you want to run it on your CentOS.

Comment: They also have a page just for installation and there is a section for [Manually compiling on Redhat-based distros](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#manually-compiling-on-redhat-based-distros-such-as-fedora).

Comment: Oki doki! (^__^)

Comment: Note that it is a good idea to build it from source, but NOT to install it from source. Instead turn it into a package and install that. This will come in very helpful when you later decide to upgrade.